# Show same contents on page in dialog box using button click in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have two pages .I am able to show page on clicking the button but i need to show same content as a dialog box on same screen without changing the screen. I need to show dialog box having same field in page .Here is my code in fiddle. on clicking the add button new page is open but i need the dialog box.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravi1989/nLJR7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```js
$.mobile.changePage($("#UserSettingScreen"), {
    transition: "slide",
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: false,
    role: 'dialog'          // you can use role: 'dialog' to open a dialog
});
```

Here is **[jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aSkKC/)** demo.

**UPDATE**

1) You can close a dialog programmatically by calling `dialog('close')` method like so

```js
$("#case_dialog_cancel").on("click", function(){
    $("#CaseInformationScreen").dialog('close');    
});
```

Here is updated **[jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VT4bf/)**.

2) You can theme an overlay. Read more about [`overlayTHeme`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/). If you for some reason want to get rid of the overlay completely or make it transparent - google for hakish ways. Here is one link [Transparent jQuery mobile dialogs](http://tqcblog.com/2012/04/19/transparent-jquery-mobile-dialogs/)

Comment: Yes i need the same thing But I don't need cross button on dialog.Seondly there is black background while displaying dialog  (i think there is masking ) is it possible to remove that ?

Comment: I need to remove dialog on cancel button not on cross  button.?

Comment: I am able to remove cross button on dialog .. using data-close-btn="none". Here is my update fiddle need same functionality on cancel button .Second remove masking ?http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravi1989/aSkKC/1/